# How does a World Wonder look like in Travian 4?

Tags: travian

I know how it looks in Travian 3, but I guess it's different in Travian 4.
Does anyone have a screenshot or something?

Comment: No way, someone else that plays Travian! :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete list of pictures of this building(travian v4.2):

[Wonder of The world http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_1-ltr.png](http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_1-ltr.png) [Wonder of The world http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_2-ltr.png](http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_2-ltr.png)
[Wonder of The world http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_3-ltr.png](http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_3-ltr.png) [Wonder of The world http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_4-ltr.png](http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_4-ltr.png)
[Wonder of The world http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_5-ltr.png](http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_5-ltr.png) [Wonder of The world http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_6-ltr.png](http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_6-ltr.png)
[Wonder of The world http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_7-ltr.png](http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_7-ltr.png) [Wonder of The world http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_8-ltr.png](http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_8-ltr.png)
[Wonder of The world http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_9-ltr.png](http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_9-ltr.png) [Wonder of The world http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_10-ltr.png](http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_10-ltr.png)
[Wonder of The world http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_11-ltr.png](http://ts6.travian.com/gpack/travian_Travian_4.2_StuffyStuffDeploy/img/g/g40_11-ltr.png)

Answer (score 5):

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Cool, you didn't have to post this cw, but I'll delete my post since it's incomplete and apparently kinda wrong. :)

Comment: Heh, no problem :) Anyway, I have to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here we are, ~30 seconds old screenshot of a WW at level 97 in T4. =)

[image]

Comment: Very nice, looks like it changed since I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, their [answer's page](http://t4.answers.travian.com/?aid=73) shows this image:

[image: Travian 4 Wonder of the World Village]

Admittedly, I don't play Travian but since this is located in the "Wonder of the World" answer on **t4**.answers.travian.com, I think that's probably what they look like.

Comment: That's the old one. Travian Answers hasn't updated their picture to T4 yet.